# PHP - Rearrange array by specific index

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, indexing

For example I have the following code:

```
$sample = array(apple, orange, banana, grape);
```

I want to rearrange this array, by making `$sample[2]` the new `$sample[0]`, while keeping the same order throughout the array.

Output should be:

```
Array ( [0] => banana [1] => grape [2] => apple [3] => orange)
```

Comment: Sorry for being so vague, but what if this array will range from 2 fruits to 10 fruits in size, and I want to rearrange this array from a random index. So say the array has 6 values, and i want to rearrange starting at the 3rd index or 4th index or a random index.

Comment: I edited my answer to include a function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`array_shift()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) as many times as you need...

```
$sample = array('apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'grape');

$fruit = array_shift($sample);
$sample[] = $fruit;
// now $sample will be array('orange', 'banana', 'grape', 'apple');
```

So say you want to make a function:

```
function rearrange_array($array, $key) {
    while ($key > 0) {
        $temp = array_shift($array);
        $array[] = $temp;
        $key--;
    }
    return $array;
}
```

Now, using `rearrange_array($sample, 2)` you can rearrange the sample array to your desired output.