# Reorder the elements in an array using php

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array and it is changeable from time to time.

```
Array
(
    [For Sale] => For Sale
    [Sold] => Sold
    [To Let] => To Let
    [Let] => Let
    [Under Offer] => Under Offer
    [Exchanged] => Exchanged
    [Withdrawn] => Withdrawn
    [Acquired] => Acquired
)
```

No matter what's the initial sequence was but when the page loads  it should look like

```
Array
    (
        [For Sale] => For Sale       
        [Under Offer] => Under Offer
        [Exchanged] => Exchanged
        [Withdrawn] => Withdrawn
        [Acquired] => Acquired
        [Sold] => Sold
        [To Let] => To Let
        [Let] => Let
    )
```

Basically these three elements should stay at the bottom of the array.

```
[Sold] => Sold
[To Let] => To Let
[Let] => Let
```

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Format using foreach

Comment: Simply extract them then append them again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - Rearrange array by specific index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15936309/php-rearrange-array-by-specific-index)

Comment: first unset the value with taking them in a variable and then push these values into the array.

Comment: You should never rely on a dictionary (associative indexed array) having keys in any specific order, even if PHP allows it. If you need ordering, use an ordinary array, even if it's slightly more complicated. In **this** case, I think you ought to enlarge the scope of the question -- *why* do you need that array in that order? And what does it do? Otherwise you're likely to hit a XY Problem issue.

Comment: It might be better to look at how you create this array in the first place. Its always better to fix the problem **at source** rather than write extra code to fiddle things later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I've used `in_array()` to match the key with the given keys `'Sold','To Let','Let'`, then unset that key from `$input` array and push that key value to the array.

```
<?php
$input = array(
    'For Sale' => 'For Sale',
    'Sold' => 'Sold',
    'To Let' => ' To Let',
    'Let' => 'Let',
    'Under Offe' => 'Under Offer',
    'Exchanged' => 'Exchanged',
    'Withdrawn' => 'Withdrawn',
    'Acquired' => 'Acquired'
);

foreach ($input as $key => $val) {
    if (in_array($key, array('Sold', 'To Let', 'Let'))) {
        unset($input[$key]);
        $input[$key] = $val;
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($input);
?>
```

This will Output :

```
Array
(
    [For Sale] => For Sale
    [Under Offe] => Under Offer
    [Exchanged] => Exchanged
    [Withdrawn] => Withdrawn
    [Acquired] => Acquired
    [Sold] => Sold
    [To Let] =>  To Let
    [Let] => Let
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Let you array name is `$arr`.
First store the values in a variable and then unset them, after that use `array_push` to store them at the last of the array.

```
$sold = $arr['Sold'];
unset($arr['Sold']);

$to_let = $arr['To Let']; 
unset($arr['To Let']);

$let = $arr['Let']; 
unset($arr['Let']);

array_push($arr, $sold, $to_let, $let);
```

Answer (score 1):

You must format your data using foreach.

```
$data = [
 'For Sale' => For Sale
 'Sold' => Sold
 'To Let' => To Let
 'Let' => Let
 'Under Offer' => Under Offer
 'Exchanged' => Exchanged
 'Withdrawn' => Withdrawn
 'Acquired' => Acquired
];

$newData = [];

foreach($data as $key => $val) {
   $newData[] = [
       'For Sale' => $val['For Sale'],
       'Under Offer' => $val['Under Offer'],
       'Exchanged' => $val['Exchanged'],
       'Withdrawn' => $val['Withdrawn'],
       'Acquired' => $val['Acquired'],
       'Sold' => $val['Sold'],
       'To Let' => $val['To Let'],
       'Let' => $val['Let']
   ]
}

print_r($newData);
```

Answer (score -1):

Short and effective solution using `array_multisort` function with "custom order"(few dimensions sorting):

```
// $arr is your initial array
$custom_order = ['F'=> 0,'S' => 5,'T' => 6,'L' =>7,'U' => 1,'E' => 2,'W' => 3,'A' => 4];
array_multisort($custom_order, SORT_ASC, $arr);

print_r($arr);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [For Sale] => For Sale
    [Under Offer] => Under Offer
    [Exchanged] => Exchanged
    [Withdrawn] => Withdrawn
    [Acquired] => Acquired
    [Sold] => Sold
    [To Let] => To Let
    [Let] => Let
)
```

---

Or another(even better) approach using `uksort` and `array_search` functions:

```
$custom_order = ['For Sale','Under Offer','Exchanged','Withdrawn','Acquired','Sold','To Let','Let'];
uksort($arr, function($a, $b) use($custom_order){
    return array_search($a,$custom_order) - array_search($b,$custom_order);
});
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php