# Rearrange array value in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have a problem to rearrange the array.This is my final array:

```
Array
(
    [5833261e-dc14-48e3-9ee1-682a7f000201] => Array
        (
            [344] => apple - 344
            [345] => apple - 345
            [acc_name] => Apple 1233 - acc_name
        )

    [58332069-fab4-44c7-9ac9-487b7f000201] => Array
        (
            [343] => apple 123456 - 343
            [acc_name] => Orange Test - acc_name
        )
)
```

I want to rearrange this to like below:

```
Array
    (
        [Apple 1233 - acc_name] => Array
            (
                [344] => apple - 344
                [345] => apple - 345
            )

        [Orange Test - acc_name] => Array
            (
                [343] => apple 123456 - 343                
            )
    )
```

So guys can you please achieve this output array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like below:-

```
$new_array = array();
foreach ($array as $key=>$val){
$acc_name = $val['acc_name'];
unset($array[$key]['acc_name']);
     $new_array[$acc_name] = $array[$key];
}
echo "<pre/>";print_r($new_array);
```

https://eval.in/715323

***Note:- After completion you can assign this new array to your original array like `$array = $new_array`***

***As per comments do one thing:-***

```
$new_array = array();
foreach ($array as $key=>$val){
$acc_name = $val['acc_name'];
unset($array[$key]['acc_name']);
     $new_array[$acc_name][] = $array[$key];
}
echo "<pre/>";print_r($new_array);
```

***Note:- In array if same indexes are coming the the new data replaced the older-one. So try the second solution***

Comment: Thanks it's working nice..But it removes some of the inner array.I don't know why it happens?

Comment: I got it..It overwrite the same acc_name arrays.How to resolve it.@Anant

Answer (score 0):

Read this link, May be It will helpful for you

> [PHP - Rearrange array by specific index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15936309/php-rearrange-array-by-specific-index)

Comment: ,Thanks ..But i need to last value of the inner array as rearrange into my main array key value.